# Gujrati text is not rendered correctly in my existing pdf

Tags: python, fpdf, pymupdf

I have used Fitz library(pymupdf sub-module) to insert text in existing pdf.
also, I have used the google trans module to translate the text
whenever I run the script the text is not rendered correctly
o/p : રવ્ નિદર નાકરાણી
Expected O/P : રવિન્દ્ર નાકરાણી

```
import fitz

def add_text_to_pdf(pdf_path, output_path,  text_to_add):
    # Open the PDF
    pdf_document = fitz.open(pdf_path)
    # set coordinnates for text
    coordinates = (175,215)

    # Get the number of pages in the PDF
    num_pages = pdf_document.page_count

    for page_num in range(num_pages):
        # Get the page
        if page_num == 2:
            page = pdf_document[page_num]
            new_ste = text_to_add
                
            page.insert_text((coordinates[0], coordinates[1]), str(new_ste),fontfile = font_path ,fontsize = 13,color = (0,0,0),fontname = 'Shruti')
    
    # Save the modified PDF
    pdf_document.save(output_path)
    pdf_document.close()
    
# Example usage
if __name__ == "__main__": 
    input_pdf_path = file_path
    output_pdf_path = "Outpugt.pdf"
    translator = Translator()
    result = translator.translate('Ravindra Nakrani', src='en',dest='gu')
    print(result.text)
    text_to_add = result.text
    add_text_to_pdf(input_pdf_path, output_pdf_path, text_to_add)
```

Comment: This is due to the fact that your text insertion method **_does not support text shaping_**.
Your language however does need that - so please use `Page` method [insert_htmlbox](https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/page.html#Page.insert_htmlbox). In this way, you can arbitrarily mix languages in any font and styling (HTML-based). The method uses HarfBuzz for text shaping. **Note:** I am a maintainer and the original creator of [PyMuPDF](https://pypi.org/project/PyMuPDF/).

Comment: @JorjMcKie The insert _htmlbox() method prints any random Gujarati(language) text.
That method is not works properly please check the issue.

Comment: Where did you post the issue? I am adding another example below with your text.

Comment: @JorjMcKie Yes, you are right. I have checked and understand that, The main issue comes from the text translation side.I'll give you a example, 
ex :
result = translator.translate('Happy', src='en',dest='gu')
O/p: ખુશ
Expected o/p : હે પી

Comment: You are welcome! If you have questions down the road, just use this [Discord](https://discord.gg/BJWR3hnC) channel.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a multi-language / multi-font example using [Page.insert_htmlbox](https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/page.html#Page.insert_htmlbox):

```py
import fitz

greetings = (
    "Hello, World!",  # english
    "Hallo, Welt!",  # german
    "سلام دنیا!",  # persian
    "வணக்கம், உலகம்!",  # tamil
    "สวัสดีชาวโลก!",  # thai
    "Привіт Світ!",  # ucranian
    "שלום עולם!",  # hebrew
    "ওহে বিশ্ব!",  # bengali
    "你好世界！",  # chinese
    "こんにちは世界！",  # japanese
    "안녕하세요, 월드!",  # korean
    "नमस्कार, विश्व !",  # sanskrit
    "हैलो वर्ल्ड!",  # hindi
)
doc = fitz.open()  # make a new empty PDF
page = doc.new_page()  # give it an empty page
rect = (50, 50, 200, 500)  # define a small rectangle on it

# concatenate the greetings into one string.
text = " ... ".join([t for t in greetings])
page.insert_htmlbox(rect, text)  # place into the rectangle

# make subset fonts
doc.subset_fonts()

# save with maximum compression / garbage collection
doc.save(__file__.replace(".py", ".pdf"), garbage=3, deflate=True)
```

**Note:** I am a maintainer and the original creator of [PyMuPDF](https://pypi.org/project/PyMuPDF/).

Answer (score 1):

```py
import fitz
doc = fitz.open()
page = doc.new_page()
r = (100, 100, 200, 150)
text = "રવિન્દ્ર નાકરાણી"
page.insert_htmlbox(r, text)
doc.ez_save("gujrati.pdf")
```

Result looks like your text for me ...

[image]

You can also supply your own font - instead of letting PyMuPDF choosing one from the Google Notos repository (which is shown here). This must be done using CSS-styling intructions `@font-face` and `font-family`.